# Movable parameters in std::thread constructor (Visual C++ 2012)

Tags: c++, multithreading, rvalue-reference, visual-c++-2012, stdthread

I run into problem with rvalue references in MSVC 2012.

```
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <future>

void foo(std::promise<std::string> &&prms) { /* some code */ }

int main() {
  std::promise<std::string> prms;
  // std::future<std::string> ftr = prms.get_future();
  std::thread th(&foo, std::move(prms));

  // some other code
}
```

Compiler says: *error C2664: 'void (std::promise<_Ty> &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::promise<_Ty>' to 'std::promise<_Ty> &&'*

Is there my mistake (then how to fix it) or compiler issue (then I'd like to know origin of such behaviour)?

Comment: @KerrekSB - Actually, this is a code sample from Bartocz Milewski. Have a look at [his post](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2009/03/03/broken-promises-c0x-futures/) (section *future*). I'd like to know, why I cannot compile it.

Comment: I'd like to know why Bartocz is trying to move that promise.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I can guess, that this is a way to rid off problems with going out of scope. That problems are possible in case lvalue reference `promise`

Comment: @Loom: And that doesn't break the future?

Comment: @Loom: Hmm.. well, Bartosz's `asyncFun` takes the promise by value. Try that. You're right though that this only works if the thread is constructed from an rvalue reference, and thus your original function with the rvalue reference *should* also work.

Comment: I'm deleting my original comment, because it's grossly misleading. The `thread` does copy the arguments, but it also preserves their value category when calling the function proper. Note that moving from the promise is highly desirable so that you can safely let the promise go out of scope (which you couldn't do if it were still active).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue in the Visual C++ 2012 implementation of `std::thread`.  See the following bug on Microsoft Connect:

> [std::thread constructor doesn't handle movable object](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/729886)

The response to that bug states:

> We attempted to fix this during VC11's development, but it exploded horribly and we had to revert the change. As it turns out, std::thread can't be powered by `bind()`, because thread needs to move its arguments, and `bind()` is forbidden from doing so (since bound functors should be repeatedly invokable, without their bound arguments being moved-from). So we'll need to reimplement `std::thread`'s ctor to avoid using `bind()`.